# Add php extentions to xampp 7.3 on linux mint

Tags: xampp, linux-mint

I need to provide a set of extensions for my local xampp 7.3(on Linux Mint 19). Into the php.ini  i'v added lines like extension="intl.so" for an every necessary extention.
When promting /opt/lampp/bin$ ./php -v, I get the following set of Warnings about all the extensions I added into the php.ini:
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so' (tried: /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so

Indeed the mentioned folder /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731 does not include these .so files, only loader-wizard.php, opcache.so, pdo_dblib.so, pgsql.so and some files for ioncube.

The dafault folder for extensions /opt/lampp/include/php/ext/ includes .h files. For example: 
/opt/lampp/include/php/ext/xml$ ls
expat_compat.h  php_xml.h

how can you resolve the issue? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly have you done to **install** these extensions? Adding a line only does not cause them to be installed

Comment: nothing else. What should I do then?

Comment: download  extensions and put them into the mentioned folder?

Comment: If I try to install extensions like this: sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl.  It works only for the global php version, not for for that version in xampp.

Comment: Why don't you use the individual component packages provided from your package manager? Either use them (means: install Apache, MySQL, PHP, extensions through the package manager), or go the hard way and find a way to do so on XAMPP (which is, according to user forums, not that simple)

Comment: Quote from https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=77256: "FInally,if you really need a binary module which is not part of Xampp, there is no way to adapt it."

Comment: I use xampp, because it is easy to install (as one package) and I can have several local servers with different versions of php. It is critical for some projects,. Thank you for the link. I have never thought of xampp, as such a closed system.

Comment: @NicoHaase Great first comment from you, but you did only give half of the relevant text from the AF forum. As Nobbie goes on to say, "You [only] can compile new modules by yourself, but this requires a working development environment as well as sophisticated skills, its easier done on Linux than on Windows.". Now, the OP may very well not be in a position to build modules themselves, but nevertheless it should be possible. So XAMPP isn't closed, merely bounded by default in terms of what it comes with as standard.